# Why so few acceptances here?

Tags: support

Why do so few questions have an **accepted** answer on this site?

Why do I not see comments written to the question authors, strongly encouraging them to accept an answer, if a good one was written, or to say in a comment why none of the answers submitted so far are not suitable for acceptance?

Comment: I've been asking myself the same question. Do some users even *know* about accepting answers? Or are the answerers just being used and then tossed to one side, until help is needed again. Is ELL a sort of disposable and very cheap—it's gratis!—online source of grammar corrections. (Not all  questions are about grammar, I know.)

Comment: @AlanCarmack  What's the situation like today on ELL, is it identical to 2013?  Although this question seems to be an exact duplicate, I believe the reasons for the lack of accepted answers are not identical. First of all, ELL is no longer in Beta. Second, it's true that three years ago many of ELL's contributors came from and were active in EL&U, their main concern was to successfully  launch ELL.

Comment: Related discussions: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/, http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/3179/, http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/3088/

Comment: @Mari-LouA The purpose of marking this question a duplicate is to keep the discussion in one place, and not to say "yeah, we already have decided this."

Comment: @ColleenV  if you want to close this question as a duplicate, I cannot do anything against it. But I expressed why I think the question needs to be updated.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The answers need to be updated for certain - the question is the same. I looked over the top scored answer of the earlier question and it is still relevant today. There's plenty of room for more answers and discussion, but let's keep it together instead of scattered across multiple threads.

Comment: @ColleenV there are no "threads" on SE, Stack Exchange is a Q&A site not a forum! :) "wink"

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you were talking about the main site, you would be correct, but Meta is for discussions, so they are threads. :)